# How to replace a single component inside a JPanel that is one of the frame's panels

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel, jtextfield

I'm using IntelliJ and I have a form full of components placed inside several `JPanel` containers. I would like to change only a single component of a single panel when the button is pressed. I tried to remove all the components of that panel and add what I need but no results.

To be precise I would like a `JLabel` to become a `JTextField`.

How can I do this without drawing the GUI again and only changing that component?

Comment: Use a [`CardLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5786005/418556). Add the label and text field to a panel with card layout. Add that panel to the GUI.

Comment: BTW - please actually *read* the description of tags before adding them to a question. The [tag:replace] relates to strings, not components.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thank you! I'm sorry for the extra-tag, I will read the descriptions next time!

Answer (score -1):

You should use the `jframe.remove(Component comp)` method and than use the `jframe.add(Component comp)`.finally, don't forget the `jframe.revalidate()` method to update your `JFrame`.
for example:

```
JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JLabel l = new JLabel("hello");
        f.add(l);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        JTextField tf = new JTextField();
        f.remove(l);
        f.add(tf);
        f.revalidate();
```

After 3 seconds, the `JLabel` in the `JFrame` will replaced by a `JTextField`.

Comment: (1-) The requirement states: *I have a form full of components...* - yes removing the component is easy, but how do you know where to insert the component back into the panel? This is why the `CardLayout` should be used.